# "Invalid Assertion" when using LEAD/LAG, Offset greater than 1, IGNORE NULLS, and single-row partitions

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

Likely this is a bug, but I'm curious if we are just overlooking something or if anyone else has ran into this.

When using [`LAG()`/`LEAD()`](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/lead.html) in Databricks SQL an *"Invalid Assertion"* errors is thrown with the combination of:

1. `IGNORE NULLS`
2. `offset` greater than `1`
3. a `PARTITION BY` that could cause single-row partitions

Errors:

```
SELECT c1, c2, 
  LEAD(c2, 2) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c1) as c3
FROM VALUES (1,3),(2,4),(2,3),(2,NULL) tab(c1, c2);
```

Works (adding a new row so that all partitions contain enough rows to satisfy the `offset`):

```
SELECT c1, c2, 
  LEAD(c2, 2) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c1) as c3
FROM VALUES (1,5),(1,3),(2,4),(2,3),(2,NULL) tab(c1, c2);
```

Works (changing offset to `1`):

```
SELECT c1, c2, 
  LEAD(c2, 1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c1) as c3
FROM VALUES (1,3),(2,4),(2,3),(2,NULL) tab(c1, c2);
```

Works (removing `IGNORE NULLS`):

```
SELECT c1, c2, 
  LEAD(c2, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c1) as c3
FROM VALUES (1,3),(2,4),(2,3),(2,NULL) tab(c1, c2);
```

Comment: No, we are running on AWS